# Generate Visio compatible XML (VDX) with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visio

I need to create a web page (`.aspx`) that creates a Visio compatible XML (VDX) filed, based on my application data, and sends it to the user.

I suppose to:

- Create once with Visio a .VDX template (that will be stored in `App_Data` folder)
- Programatically load the template, edit the XML, save a copy into `Public` folder, give the user the link to download this file.

**I can't install Visio on webserver, so i must work on XML and can't use Visio Primary Interop Assembly.**

Googling, I can't find

- **Specifications** about XML rules that are used by Visio
- **Sample code** that works on VDX xml
- **3rd party DLLs** that can help development

can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you've been looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff768724.aspx

As it's standard XML you can use the classes in `System.Xml` to modify the XML you load from the template. You should have no need to use Visio Automation, therefore no need to install Visio on the webserver.

Answer (score 2):

also checkout Saveen Reddy's VisioAutomation project on GitHub, which allows you to generate VDX files without requiring Visio:

https://github.com/saveenr/VisioAutomation

Update - another resource is Visio MVP, Al Edlund's 'xmlVisio' project, also on CodePlex:

http://xmlvisio.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting links from Simon Halsey and JohnoGldsmith.
I found  [Visio Guy](http://www.visguy.com/2006/11/30/visio-and-xml-conference-resources/) which is very interesting, too.